# Variável recebendo somente 1 unico valor do fetch, como corrigir?

Tags: php, mysql

Eu preciso passar todos os valores da coluna para uma variavel, como por exemplo:

Chave -> $chave;

Conteudo -> $Conteúdo;

Então eu usei o bindColumn, mas porém na hora que executa o fetch() ele está trazendo somente 1 resultado, sendo que eu preciso de todos, já tentei utilizar o fetchAll() mas da na mesma, como fazer pra que vá todos os valores, não apenas 1 só.

Meu código atualmente:

```
<?php

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=73519225000122", "root", "");
$buscar = $pdo->prepare("SELECT chave, conteudo FROM xml WHERE modelo = '55' LIMIT 100 ");
$buscar->execute();
$buscar->bindColumn(1, $chave);
$buscar->bindColumn(2, $conteudo);
$linha = $buscar->fetch();

echo json_encode($chave);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Você deve buscar todos os dados da consulta SQL usando, por exemplo, a função do `PDO` `fetch` (mas poderia ser outra também), então:** você poderá concatenar toda uma coluna em uma única variável, dentro do laço, no caso, é usado o `while`. Para concatenar alguma coluna da sua `table`, dentro do `while`, você usa um ponto `.`.

No seu caso, fica:

```
       $chave_2 = "", $conteudo_2 = "";
       while ($linha = $buscar->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
             //Concatenação (.=):
             $chave_2 .=  $linha['chave'];
             //Concatenação (.=):
             $conteudo_2 .=  $linha['conteudo'];
       }
```

> Lembrando que a função `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` com o atributo `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` *"retorna uma matriz indexada pelo nome da coluna, conforme retornado no seu conjunto de resultados"*

Fonte: [fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.fetch.php)

> **Tenta o seguite:**

```
     $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=73519225000122", "root", "");
        $buscar = $pdo->prepare("SELECT chave, conteudo FROM xml WHERE modelo = '55' LIMIT 100 ");
        $buscar->execute();
        $buscar->bindColumn(1, $chave);
        $buscar->bindColumn(2, $conteudo);

       /* $chave = [], $conteudo = [];
         while ($linha = $buscar->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
              array_push($chave, $linha['chave']);
              array_push($conteudo, $linha['conteudo']);
            }

       var_dump(json_encode($chave));
       var_dump(json_encode($conteudo));*/

      //Esta parte deve resolver pra você:

       $chave_2 = "", $conteudo_2 = "";
       while ($linha = $buscar->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
             $chave_2 .=  $linha['chave'];
             $conteudo_2 .=  $linha['conteudo'];
       }

       var_dump($chave_2);
       var_dump($conteudo_2);
```

Comment: Deu certo, mas deixa eu te perguntar, como eu faria pra deixar todo os registros em cima da variavel $chave e o conteúdo todo em cima da variável $conteudo? Pq dai conforme caso eu queria gerar arquivos apartir do conteudo, eu consigo definir o nome de cada arquivo com o valor que vir da variavel $chave, pq eles iriam rodar juntos;

Tipo 
linha -> chave:[11111111111111];
linha -> conteudo:[11111111111111111111];

Logo o arquivo teria o nome 111111111111.xml por exemplo, com o conteudo dentro.

Comment: Vou editar a resposta.

Comment: Ahhhh agora intendi como fazer, pow Taffa, valeu mesmo pela ajuda cara! Muito obrigado mesmo, tu nao sabe o quanto eu tava batendo cabeça pra resolver isso, fiz muita pesquisa no google e em grupos de facebook antes de postar aqui e tu me ajudou pra caramba, valeu!

Comment: Não se esqueça de votar e aceitar a resposta. [kkkk]

Comment: Sou novo por arqui kkk mas já fiz!

Answer (score 1):

O `fetch` só pega uma linha por vez, foi feito para ser usado em loops. Parece que você quer o comportamento do [`fetchAll`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php). Mas evite usar `fetchAll` se forem muitos dados.

Comment: Eu usei o fetchAll mas também continuou trazendo somente 1 registro. :/